# Can the sitemap files be in a folder if the sitemapindex is in the root path?

Tags: sitemap

I want to have a sitemap structure where the sitempasindex file is located in the root path (example.com/sitemaps.xml) and it references several sitemap[n].xml files located in a folder (example.com/static/sitemap1.xml). Those sitemap[n].xml files link to webpages that are in the rooth path (like example.com/helloworld.html).

Is that posible? I'm asking because I know that if the sitemap.xml file is placed within a folder, it can only contain webpages that are under that folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you easily have
example.com/sitemap-index.xml
point to e.g.
example.com/sub1/sitemap.xml
and
example.com/sub2/sitemap.xml

however each sitemap.xml should only contains URLs within each their subfolder. (From your question, it seems you have those sitemap.xml files link to paths in root. I *doubt* that works, but you could try run a small test and submit to Google. If no errors then...)

Answer (score 0):

The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/.

From google perspective, they should be available on main root of the website. http://example.com/sitemap.xml, When you submit it through the subdir in webmaster tool "http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml" google won't crawl it and always showing us pending index status.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct as my sitemap is under /sitemap/sitemap.txt and when submitted through webmaster tools it is indexed.